# Are there security issues when dynamically loading external content into a page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, security, dynamic, exploit

I'm building a site and I would like to have external content dynamically loaded in a div using jQuery. The content could be a google search page, where one can navigate without actually leaving the site. Could someone exploit this and drive to a content of his own and run malicious code inside my site? Are there ways to prevent this? Is using an iframe the best bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main concerns, when doing cross-domain AJAX are [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).  A quick Google search, revealed [this article](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/aug/cross-domain-ajax-insecurity).  So instead of paraphrasing, I'd just reccommend you go and read it and follow some of the links to more in-depth discussions on the expoits you are opening yourself up to.